DAX table calculation
As I am new to Powerbi, I need one table calculation to implement in the dashboard, however, I'm unable to conduct this calculation. I need help on this and I'm also not sure if this possible to implement in powerbi?
I need to calculate the numbers according to the yearly total in the first row and the result out of that needs to be starting from second row of the column and so on. How this calculation can be created?
Please see attached screenshot below :

I have tried various calculations, but none of those seemed to be working. for instance below calculations
TotalRequests provides the yearly total.
Total_test = 

VAR TotalRequests = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(fx[request_id]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(fx),
        fx[Fiscal_Year] < SELECTEDVALUE(FY[Fiscal_Year]) &&
        (fx[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = "9999" ||
        fx[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= SELECTEDVALUE(FY[Fiscal_Year]))
    )
)
RETURN
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(fx[Fiscal_Year]) &&
    (HASONEVALUE(Fiscal_Month[Fiscal_month]) && FILTER(Fiscal_Month,Fiscal_Month[Receive_Month] = "October")),
    TotalRequests,
    BLANK()
)


What are the relationship between your tables ?

@AmiraBedhiafi I have 2 tables date and main table, both mapped with a date. Everything is working fine. I just need to know if this type of calculation that is mentioned above in the monthly breakdown is possible in the dax where Column D numbers can be added to the Column A and Column A's first row should be a yearly total number. Is this possible?

Can you please update your question with your model ? The input and expected output
